# What is the default session timeout and how to configure it when using the Spring Session with Redis as the backend?

Tags: redis, session-timeout, spring-session

My application currently use [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) together with Redis as the backend.

I searched into the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/) for Spring Session but was not able to find what the *default session timeout* is when using that module. Also I am not sure how to change that ***default timeout*** if necessary.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The easiest way to configure session timeout when using redis repository is

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 60)
```

OR @EnableRedissonHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 1200) if redisson dependency is there.

The session *expires* when it is no longer available in the repository.
Timeout can be configured with `setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(int)` on both `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` and `MapSessionRepository`. Default value is **30 minutes**.

If you are using spring boot, then as of version 1.3 it will automatically sync the value with the `server.session.timeout` property from the application configuration.

Note that one of the shortcomings when using spring session is that `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`s are not invoked.

If you need to react on session expiration events you can subscribe to `SessionDestroyedEvent` application event of your spring application.

Comment: @balteo yes it is 30 mins not secs. I updated the answer thanks.

Comment: Saved me alot of time!

Answer (score 8):

`server.session.timeout` is deprecated and was replaced with `server.servlet.session.timeout` in Spring Boot 2.0.

Comment: How about WebFlux, the option didn't work with webflux

Comment: What is the difference between the properties `spring.session.timeout`and 
`server.servlet.session.timeout` ? 

I want to control `@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = ...)` by an external property.