# Grails 3 session timeout not working when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: spring, session, tomcat, grails, grails3.2.0

I'm using **Grails 3.2.3**. I've increased the session timeout as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30861747/2405040 i.e. adding the following in `application.yml`:

```
server:
   session:
      timeout: 604800 #one week in seconds
```

This is working fine while in development i.e. `session.getMaxInactiveInterval()` returns 604800 but when I'm deploying the WAR on a Tomcat (using **Tomcat 8.5.6**), this session timeout setting is not reflected and the value is default to 1800 seconds.

`"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"` is set to `provided` in `build.gradle`.

(I was previously modifying the session timeout as I described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382383/2405040 but later I realized that, that is related to embedded tomcat so switched to above `application.yml` setting)

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A best guess would be, that the Tomcat container you deploy to does not use the

```
server:
   session:
      timeout: 604800
```

value you set, as this is only a directive to the embedded Tomcat container. When you deploy as war, you have to configure the Tomcat server you deploy to:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Yeah, I think so too! But is there a way we can increase the timeout from within the app like Grails 2?

Comment: Perhaps this blog entry can be of help: http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-java-configuration-session-timeout. I got that link from this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103852/spring-boot-session-timeout