# server.session.timeout in application.yml is not used when deployed to a tomcat as a war

Tags: grails, grails3.2.0

I have this configuration in my application.yml

```
server:
    contextPath: /appname
    session:
        timeout: 7200  # 2 hours in seconds
```

This works fine when i run in Intellij IDEA, but when i deploy the build .war file to a tomcat instance this is ignored. Is this a bug or is it not expected to work like this?

Also i seem to be unable to locate a specification of what can be written in application.yml. Anyone know where this can be found?

How about the application.groovy config file? Cant seem to locate a specification for this?

My environment:

- Grails version: 3.2.8
- Gradle version: 3.4.1
- Intellij IDEA version: 2017.1.2
- Tomcat version: 8.0.26
      JDK Version: 1.8.0_45

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215649/grails-3-session-timeout-not-working-when-deployed-to-tomcat seems like a similar question. Basically application.yml unsure of a specification, depends on plugin used and so forth. In short appilcation.groovy can be created in the same path/folder as application.yml. Your application will read both files and you can configure it in the yml style or in the older .groovy style which was `some.element.key=value`

Comment: This is indeed the same problem. I will test if it works if i move it to the .groovy file instead. I an still thinking that this is a bug. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: the answer on that page states you have to actually configure tomcat for that - so doubt it's a bug

Comment: This is something that have allways been configurable in config.groovy (in grails v2.x) and i would think that if this have been removed, it should be stated in the migrationguide. This is why i would suspect it being a bug.

Comment: Yes but grails 2 was not using spring boot, entirely new technology in grails 3. You should read the comments at bottom of answer which point to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103852/spring-boot-session-timeout

Comment: I do realise that i can program a solution to this. It just seems a tad too excessive to have to do an implementation of this. I just got around to experiment with setting it in the application.groovy configfile instead and it seems to work. I have tried to set server.session.timeout = 50 and a timeout occurs after 50 secs. It just seems odd that the two application.xx configfiles dosnt offer same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a Grails 3 app to a standalone tomcat application you should not use springboot `server.session.timeout` configuration property. That it is only for an embeedded server.

[image: Spring boots - sever.session.timeout - Embedded Server configuration]

To configure a session timeout in a SpringBoot app (Grails 3 app is built on top of SpringBoot app) deployed into a standalone tomcat you have two choices:

**A)** Timeout for every app deployed in that tomcat instance.

You could edit the session timeout directly in tomcat configuration files:

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml
```

Look out for the block:

```
<!-- ==================== Default Session Configuration ================= -->
<!-- You can set the default session timeout (in minutes) for all newly   -->
<!-- created sessions by modifying the value below.   -->

 <session-config>
     <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
```

**B)** You can add a web.xml file in your Grails 3 app, with the timeout you need per app.

Create a file in the path 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml' with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <session-config>
     <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
 </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

**C)** You can also use tomcat's `HttpSession setMaxInactiveInterval(seconds)` method to set in your Groovy code.

```
if (grailsApplication.config.getProperty("session.timeout")?.isInteger())
    // session timeout in seconds
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(grailsApplication.config.session.timeout as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that with the (current latest) Grails 5.x and spring boot 2.5 the correct property  name is `server.servlet.session.timeout` and hence the application.yml config would go like this:

```
server:   
    servlet:
      session:
        timeout: 3600  #seconds
```

Spring boot docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.5/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.servlet.session.timeout